# Instalar o docker no Mint

Tags: linux, docker, mint

Estou tentando instalar o docker no meu Notebook com Linux Mint 19 Cinamon 64 bits utilizando [este](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) tutorial

Só que ao chegar nessa linha

```
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
```

1. Me deparo com os seguintes problemas

```
sudo: curl: command not found
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

2. E se eu tentar instalar o curl usando o 
   sudo apt-get install curl

Me retorna isso aqui

```
Você pode querer executar 'apt --fix-broken install' para corrigí-los.
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 curl : Depende: libcurl4 (= 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6) mas não será instalado
 mongodb-org-server : Depende: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) mas não será instalado
 warsaw : Depende: libcurl3 mas não será instalado ou
                   libcurl4 mas não será instalado
E: Dependências desencontradas. Tente 'apt --fix-broken install' sem nenhum pacote (ou especifique uma solução).
```

3. Se eu tento isso `apt --fix-broken install` não funciona
4. Se eu tentar assim `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install` o comando funciona mas nao resolve. Tenho o seguinte retorno

   The following additional packages will be installed:
     libcurl3
   Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
     libcurl3
   0 pacotes atualizados, 1 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 0 não atualizados.
   É preciso baixar 214 kB de arquivos.
   Depois desta operação, 644 kB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.

   Você quer continuar? [S/n] S
   Obter:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libcurl3 amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 [214 kB]
   Baixados 214 kB em 2s (134 kB/s)
   A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado libcurl3:amd64.
   (Lendo banco de dados ... 333652 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
   A preparar para desempacotar .../libcurl3_7.58.0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
   A descompactar libcurl3:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu2) ...
   Configurando libcurl3:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu2) ...
   A processar 'triggers' para libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ..

Ai se eu tento novamente na opção 1, começa tudo de novo, os erros. Como posso tirar esses problemas para instalar o docker?

Answer (score 3):

Tente remover as libs e instalar manualmente:

```
apt remove -y libcurl4
apt install -y libcurl4 curl
```

e depois tente novemente continuar o processo de instalação:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

... Se o curl não foi instalado corretamente sugiro que se certifique que todas as depedências estão instaladas, para isso use esses comandos:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install transport-https certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
```

E depois continue o processo de instalação:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

...

---

Outra forma de instalar o docker é usando snap que é bem mais simples, primeiro instale o snap:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

Por fim instale o docker:

```
sudo snap install docker
```

Caso deseje executar o docker sem a necessidade de utilizar o sudo ou estar logado como superuser:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG $(whoami) docker
```

Reinicie o computador e para testar faça:

```
docker -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente instalar a dependência do curl manualmente:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libcurl4
```